# How to redesign the product list in magento homepage?

Tags: magento-1.9

Product list show in homepage is like below:

[image]

But, i want it shows like this :

[image]

**How?**

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have using

default Magento **new products** template file `new.phtml` ***(app/design/frontend/[Package]/[Theme]/template/catalog/product)***.

**For your requirement,you need to do two things:**

- Increase the product images size at `resize([IWidth],[Height])`.
- Second, li element size from Css

Comment: i am using custom template. and i can not find the new.phtml file.. so how? thank's before.

Comment: share your code of Custom template file code